# How to resolve "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW' error while creating view in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, create-view

I have a use case in which I need to create views in multiple databases using dynamic SQL. I realized that I can't give database name in front of the view in dynamic SQL, so used the `use` database statement in the beginning of the dynamic SQL. I'm getting the Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW' error. I am wondering if it has anything to do with the create view statement in dynamic SQL? Any pointers will be helpful?

```
SET @Sql = N'

USE ' + @DbName + '

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''DBO'' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = ''TAB_1''))
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[VW_1]'') is not null
      DROP VIEW [dbo].[VW_1]
    
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_1]
    AS
    SELECT 
    ...
    ...

END


SET @Sql = 'EXEC (''' + REPLACE(@Sql, '''', '''''') + ''')' + CASE WHEN @ServerName = @ThisServer THEN '' ELSE ' AT ' + @ServerName END
EXEC ( @Sql )
```

Comment: Your dynamic SQL as posted isn't even valid... copy it out into a query window and check. Pretty hard for us to help when its not valid in the first place. And there is no sign of a "GO" in your example. And my best guess is you are calling `exec` twice which seems unnecessary? `Print(@Sql)`  instead of executing it and see if its valid. And according to the docs you would only use `AT` when referencing a linked server - which you don't appear to be doing.

Comment: Thanks, where should I put GO?

Comment: My apologies, I meant "use", not "go".. I have updated my query.. Is there a restriction on not been able to create a view in dynamic SQL?

Comment: No... as I said your code doesn't even pass a syntax check... so it can't be what you are really using. And `AT` is only for a linked server.

Comment: Either way, this code will not work. You cannot nest the creation of a view like this. Try running your code for a single test without using dynamic SQL, make sure that works before you try converting it to dynamic.

Comment: [Here is how you do it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19335/create-view-in-a-different-database-with-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Running the script without making it dynamic helped me in narrowing down my issue. My create view statement should be the first one in the query batch but the issue is that I have to check for the existence of the table in each database before making a view out of it. Not sure how I can achieve that, while still keeping the create statement as the first one in the batch

Comment: use 2 separate dynamic query

Answer (score 2):

From [`CREATE VIEW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) docs:

> Remarks
>
> ---
>
> A view can be created only in the current database. The CREATE
> VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.

Since `CREATE VIEW` must be the first statement in a query batch you'll need to split your code into two pieces and run them separately somehow. That's why SSMS adds the `GO` command after `USE db`.

I don't know how to achieve that in dynamic SQL.

Maybe, build two dynamic SQL commands. The first command will have

```
USE db; 
-- some logic determining if the second command should run
EXEC 'CREATE VIEW AS ...'
```

The second command will have just the `CREATE VIEW` statement.

Comment: Thanks, I agree. that's the issue, but I have a condition to check for the existence of the table in that database before creating a view out of it..not sure how to achieve that